# Trying to Collapse Multiple Rows to Single Result

Tags: sql, sql-server

A rough example of my source data:

```
OrderStatus | CustomerID | OrderNbr | LoadNbr | Product | Quantity
------------+------------+----------+---------+---------+---------
   OPEN     |     1      | ORD00001 |    1    |  0012   | 12
   OPEN     |     1      | ORD00001 |    2    |  0024   | 20
```

And what I'm trying to achieve in a result:

```
 OrderStatus | CustomerID | OrderNbr | Prod01 | Quantity01 | Prod02 | Quantity02 | Ratio01 | Ratio02
-------------+------------+----------+--------+------------+--------+------------+---------+---------
    OPEN     |     1      | ORD00001 |  0012  |     12     |  0024  |   20       |  37.5   |   62.5
```

For the sake of brevity I only included 2 products. But in the data I've been given there can be upwards of 8 products.

What I've been trying:

```
WITH OrderSummary AS (
  SELECT O.OrderStatus,
         O.CustomerID,
         O.OrderNbr,
         'TotalQty' = I1.Quantity + I2.Quantity,
         'Prod01' = I1.Product,
         'Quantity01' = I1.Quantity,
         'Prod02' = I2.Product,
         'Quantity02' = I2.Quantity
  FROM   Orders O
  LEFT JOIN Orders I1 ON O.OrderNbr = I1.OrderNbr AND I1.LoadNbr = 1
  LEFT JOIN Orders I2 ON O.OrderNbr = I2.OrderNbr AND I1.LoadNbr = 2
)

SELECT  *,
        'Ratio01' = Quantity01 / TotalQty * 100,
        'Ratio02' = Quantity02 / TotalQty * 100
FROM    OrderSummary
```

Which is more or less what I've currently got running. But the results I *do* get look like this:

```
 OrderStatus | CustomerID | OrderNbr | Prod01 | Quantity01 | Prod02 | Quantity02 | Ratio01 | Ratio02
-------------+------------+----------+--------+------------+--------+------------+---------+---------
    OPEN     |     1      | ORD00001 |  0012  |     12     |  0024  |   20       |  37.5   |   62.5
    OPEN     |     1      | ORD00001 |  0012  |     12     |  0024  |   20       |  37.5   |   62.5
```

So I just tried running with a `DISTINCT` declaration which works most of the time but seems clunky.

**So the question I have** is whether I'm approaching this problem from the right angle or not. Is using joins on the same table the best way to collapse the results to a single row? Or is there a better way to achieve this? I am somewhat constrained by the environment I'm working in: I have no control over the data format given to me and I *must* present the results in a single row to the application executing the database query.

EDIT: Some additional clarification. For any given order the Status, Customer, OrderNumber, etc. would all be the same. The LoadNbr, Product, and Quantity rows would be unique between each entry. So an Order with 8 products would have 8 rows I'm trying to collapse to a single row.

Late Edit / Clarification:
In my question I had mentioned I get duplicate rows no matter what. That was a mistake. I found data in my production data that was *not* identical (some dates with different values by milliseconds). I've removed that section for anyone finding this question.

Comment: Pivot is what you are looking for, but it's more easier to do this in your front end app than sql

Comment: You *can* do this, but please don't, pivot is like regex, you start to solve a problem and end up with two, why not work with the rows as they are

Comment: If the number of rows can vary by 8 or more you're looking for a dynamic pivot - there are multiple answers on Stack Overflow for this but what happens when you have 20... 50... 500 products?

Comment: What is the maximum possible number of `LoadNbr` and therefore howm any columns do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my view the simplest way to do this is through "conditional aggregates" and not via the "pivot operator". However first your existing query would work IF you include a where clause to suppress the unwanted rows: e.g:

```
WITH OrderSummary
AS (
    SELECT
          O.OrderStatus
        , O.CustomerID
        , O.OrderNbr
        , 'TotalQty' = O.Quantity + I2.Quantity + I3.Quantity + I4.Quantity 
                    + I5.Quantity + I6.Quantity + I7.Quantity + I8.Quantity
        ,     'Prod01' = O.Product
        , 'Quantity01' = O.Quantity
        ,     'Prod02' = I2.Product
        , 'Quantity02' = I2.Quantity
        ,     'Prod03' = I3.Product
        , 'Quantity03' = I3.Quantity
        -- more of the same here
    FROM Orders O
    LEFT JOIN Orders I2 ON O.OrderNbr = I2.OrderNbr AND I2.LoadNbr = 2
    LEFT JOIN Orders I3 ON O.OrderNbr = I3.OrderNbr AND I3.LoadNbr = 3
    LEFT JOIN Orders I4 ON O.OrderNbr = I4.OrderNbr AND I4.LoadNbr = 4
    -- more of the same here
    WHERE O.LoadNbr = 1
    )
SELECT
      *
    , 'Ratio01' = Quantity01 / TotalQty * 100
    , 'Ratio02' = Quantity02 / TotalQty * 100
    , 'Ratio03' = Quantity03 / TotalQty * 100
    -- more of the same here
FROM OrderSummary
```

but this is so very ugly and has problems (e.g. TotalQty could be NULL if any of the quantities are missing.

An alternative is to use an approach like this:

```
SELECT
      OrderStatus     
    , CustomerID     
    , OrderNbr     
    , ca.TotalQty     
    , max(CASE WHEN o.LoadNbr = 1 THEN o.Product ELSE '' END) AS Product1
    , max(CASE WHEN o.LoadNbr = 1 THEN o.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Quantity1
    , max(CASE WHEN o.LoadNbr = 1 THEN round(o.Quantity * 100.0 / ca.TotalQty,2) ELSE 0 END) AS Ratio1
    , max(CASE WHEN o.LoadNbr = 2 THEN o.Product ELSE '' END) AS Product2
    , max(CASE WHEN o.LoadNbr = 2 THEN o.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Quantity2
    , max(CASE WHEN o.LoadNbr = 2 THEN round(o.Quantity * 100.0 / ca.TotalQty,2) ELSE 0 END) AS Ratio2
    -- more of the same here
FROM Orders AS O
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(q.Quantity) AS TotalQty
    FROM Orders AS q
    WHERE q.OrderNbr = o.OrderNbr     
    ) AS ca
GROUP BY
      OrderStatus     
    , CustomerID     
    , OrderNbr
```

and this can be made "dynamic" as well, like so:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ', max(CASE WHEN o.LoadNbr = ' 
  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LoadNbr) + ' THEN o.Product ELSE '''' END) AS Product' 
  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LoadNbr) + ', max(CASE WHEN o.LoadNbr = ' 
  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LoadNbr) + ' THEN o.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Quantity' 
  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LoadNbr) + ', max(CASE WHEN o.LoadNbr = ' 
  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LoadNbr) + ' THEN round(o.Quantity * 100.0 / ca.TotalQty,2) ELSE 0 END) AS Ratio' 
  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LoadNbr)
             FROM (SELECT DISTINCT LoadNbr FROM Orders) O
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
             ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
         ,1,2,'');

select @cols;

SET @sql = 'SELECT OrderStatus
    , CustomerID
    , OrderNbr
    , ca.TotalQty
    , ' + @cols + '
FROM Orders AS O
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(q.Quantity) AS TotalQty FROM Orders AS q
    WHERE q.OrderNbr = o.OrderNbr
    ) AS ca
GROUP BY OrderStatus
    , CustomerID
    , OrderNbr
    , ca.TotalQty';

select @sql;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

see [this demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/K5M7flF3)

Comment: For performance reasons probably best to remove the `DISTINCT` and instead do `FROM Orders GROUP BY LoadNbr FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')`. And obviously newer versions can just use `STRING_AGG`

Comment: The only data being summarised by distinct is loadnbr, I think the effort of that - v - group by will be negligable.

Comment: But the fact you are using concatenation means that the optimizer can't see that, and thinks it needs to re-sort and aggregate. See eg https://dbfiddle.uk/StaLhakt

Comment: Excellent! This worked for me. I found a few other bugs with the data I've been given but I'm going to be able to work out the rest with your queries as a base.

Comment: @Charlieface For simplicity (only have a phone right now) I moved the use of distinct to a subquery). Thanks.

Comment: Yes that's another option, the effect is the same.